# Changing value of an object from a different class

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I have a `ViewController.m` with a `UIButton` and a `UIWebView` on it.
I've subclassed `UIWebView` to a class that is now called `MyWebView.m`.

What is the most efficient way to change the `UIButton` outlet location value from a method that is inside `MyWebView.m`
I thought about `NSUserDefaults` but it feels to me like it's the worst way to go.

Another thought was to copy the next line and also add it inside `MyWebView.h`:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *myButton;
```

and connect it to the button from  `ViewController.m`  but I'm also not sure if that's a right thing to do.

Comment: So the view controller knows about the web view? You say no but also say the view Controller has it in its view.

Comment: The webView is inside ViewController.m. Yes.

Comment: Isn't there a better object oriented solution for that? Userdefaults and notifications doesn't like was ment to be used like that

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What is an "outlet location value"?

Answer (score 0):

What does the button title represent, conceptually? Decide that, and expose it as a string property of your web view and then have your view controller observe the property with key value observing. Or alternatively, extend UIWebViewDelegate with your own protocol, and have the view controller set itself as the web view's delegate. Then have the web view notify its delegate that this value changed.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the app delegate class for persisting the data through the application but this is also  not recommended by the good programmers.

One other way is to use Singleton class . This  creates only one object per application session so you can use the the value throughout the application also you can modify and access the value. This is the pure approach to go .You can take a look at http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/

Comment: My project already have a singleton class that handles other stuff. I guess it felt weird to add a button outlet there. Should I just add the line of code above to my singleton .h file and connect it to the button in the story board?

Comment: That doesn't work. I can't connect my button to the singleton class.